# Is there an Add Assignment (+=) or similar in Lua?

Tags: lua

I would like to know if there is a add assignment (+=) or a similar assignment in lua since I'm used to using it from other languages like Python and C#

Comment: Please refer to the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#9) to answer such questions. It lists all available operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to use `x = x + 1`.

There is a Lua transpiler called Moonscript that has this feature.